# How to train BART for text summarization using custom datset?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, summarization, huggingface-transformers

I have prepared a custom dataset for training my own custom model for text summarization. I wish to use BART as it is the state of art now. I am using Transformer Library of HuggingFace using pytorch.

But I don't know how to train a model on my own.I tried running run_train.sh on the following link:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/summarization/bart

I have loaded the CNN data into Google Colab. Still it is showing errors.

Can someone help me with how to do custom text summarization using transfer learning?
Any other models are also helpful.

Comment: The error would be helpful

Comment: Also consider having a look at [mcve]. Each question should be self-contained, and be reproducible to the visitors of your question.